# React Native - Local Images running perfectly fine in emulator but not after release

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I encountered an issue today with react native. well every time when i face any issue i almost got a solution after digging into it or in internet for couple of hours but this issue is a real headache for me now.

Issue is that i am using few images in my assets folder and when i run react-native run-android and creates a bundle in my emulator everything works fine and smooth. I can see images. But when i create assembleRelease bundle to publish my app in app store and install that in my any device. no errors prompt but i can't be able to see the images. weird !

well i also found some solution but they're outdated and post were like 2018 and old.

Please help if you know or faced this error.

Comment: How you get release apk ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try this to get release build by this code

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

If the above code doesn't work try this code with budling all assets and get the release

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] D:\react\with Github\mobilelegendsguide\android\app\src\main\res\raw\node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] D:\react\with Github\mobilelegendsguide\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources

Comment: what about this code -> `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Akila Devinda problem is that local images working in emulator but not after creating a release. and i am using ./gradlew assembleRelease only to create a release.